# Yosemite Mail.app search of gmail is not working at all

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have tried a lot of things. Most drastic was to remove the gmail accounts from mail.app, exit mail.app, turn off IMAP from the gmail side, turn it back on, re-add the gmail accounts to mail.app. Everything seems to work fine, there is no activity happening in the activity window, and yet, when I search for anything in mail.app I get zero hits. Any ideas?

Comment: when you type a single letter in the search window do you get a pop up? regardless of a account.

Comment: I get the popup with all the choices (near the search box), but no results if I confirm the letter. And by the way spotlight does find emails...???

Comment: sounds like your email data base has a problem. Go to mailbox- Rebuild.